# eBPF packet filter not giving me correct data

Tags: bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

So I've been trying to see if I could attach a eBPF packet filter to a network interface, enp32s0np1. I'm trying to catch all the incoming sender IP addresses. However, running the below code gives me weird reaction. Instead of seeing the sender IP address, I see some random numbers filled in.

Here's the code :

```
from bcc import BPF

# Network interface to be monoitored
INTERFACE = "enp32s0np1"

bpf_text = """

#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <bcc/proto.h>
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

int skb_matching(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
u8 *cursor = 0;
u64 saddr =0;
void *data_end = (void*)(long)skb->data_end;
void *data = (void*)(long)skb->data;
struct ethhdr *eth = data;

u32 nh_off = 0;
nh_off = sizeof(*eth);

/* // Code here has been blocked because this part keeps giving me errors as well..
if (data + nh_off > data_end ) { 
    bpf_trace_printk("error");
}
*/
//bpf_trace_printk("%p", data);

struct ethernet_t *ethernet = cursor_advance(cursor, sizeof(*ethernet));
struct ip_t *ip = cursor_advance(cursor,sizeof(*ip));
saddr = ip -> dst;
bpf_trace_printk("sss = %d", saddr);

bpf_trace_printk("Incoming packet!\\n");
return -1;
}

"""

from ctypes import *
import sys
import socket
import os
import struct

bpf = BPF(text=bpf_text)

function_skb_matching = bpf.load_func("skb_matching", BPF.SOCKET_FILTER)

BPF.attach_raw_socket(function_skb_matching, INTERFACE)

print("=========================packet monitor=============================\n")
bpf.trace_print()
```

and here is the result :

```
   handler27-3403  [010] ..s1 135652.183626: 0: sss = -1062731519       handler27-3403  [010] ..s1 135652.183642: 0: Incoming packet!!
   handler27-3403  [010] ..s1 135652.183691: 0: sss = -1062731518       handler27-3403  [010] ..s1 135652.183695: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135653.184712: 0: sss = -1062731519          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135653.184728: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135653.184759: 0: sss = -1062731518          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135653.184760: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135654.205715: 0: sss = -1062731519          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135654.205734: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135654.205765: 0: sss = -1062731518          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135654.205766: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135655.229752: 0: sss = -1062731519          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135655.229771: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135655.229802: 0: sss = -1062731518          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135655.229802: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135656.253777: 0: sss = -1062731519          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135656.253796: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135656.253827: 0: sss = -1062731518          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135656.253828: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.194068: 0: sss = 16842752          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.194084: 0: Incoming packet!!
   handler27-3403  [010] ..s1 135657.195105: 0: sss = 16908309       handler27-3403  [010] ..s1 135657.195111: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.213711: 0: sss = 16908288          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.213727: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.213741: 0: sss = 16842773          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.213742: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.277815: 0: sss = -1062731519          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.277832: 0: Incoming packet!!
      <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.277860: 0: sss = -1062731518          <idle>-0     [010] ..s. 135657.277861: 0: Incoming packet!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Those numbers are your IP addresses, in decimal format.** For example, if I launch your script in one terminal while I ping `8.8.8.8` in the other, I get:

```
term1$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=9.80 ms
[...]

term2$ python test.py
[...]
            ping-6545  [004] ....  1876.984747: 0: sss = 134744072            ping-6545  [004] ....  1876.984763: 0: Incoming packet!
[...]
```

The number `134744072` corresponds to IP `8.8.8.8` (you can use online [decimal-to-IP](https://www.browserling.com/tools/dec-to-ip) or [decimal-to-hex](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter) converters to check that).

You can **convert these numbers to the usual IP representation with e.g., `IPAddress` on the Python side** (see bcc's example [`tunnel_monitor`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/c2e2a26b8624492018a14d5eebd4a50b869c911f/examples/networking/tunnel_monitor/monitor.py#L40)), but you'll have to use a perf ring buffer or a map to transmit data from the kernel side to the userspace, Python side.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Also if you don't mind me asking, if I wanted to transmit every single data I retrieve to the user space and try to save it in the database, would you recommend perf_event_array map? I've done some study and it was recommended for such task. However, I don't think I've seen an example where they used this map with a socket buffer. All the examples I've seen were all used with ctx. I did read though it can be used with socket buffer? But I'm not so sure since I haven't seen one. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Oh actually I just found an example that uses skb and perf_output. I really appreciate your help :D